# How to fix CSS animation positioning

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to fix the positioning of a CSS animation. In the pictures below, I want to have my text centred towards the right. However, it keeps dropping down to the bottom. I was wondering how I could fix that.

Edit: I have added the rest of my HTML and after the "and I am a" I am using Javascript to animate the typewriting.

Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy0gX.jpg

CSS

```
#intro {
font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 34px;
line-height: 36px;
margin-top: 10%;
float: left;
animation-name: fade-in-from-top;
animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fade-in-from-top {
from { opacity: 0; margin-top: -30%; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Irene Li</title>
    <style type="text/css">a {text-decoration: none}</style>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/style_copy.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/script/animate.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/script/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="home-page-wrapper">
            <div id="navbar">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-item" id="current-navbar-item" style="margin-left": 50px">Irene Li</a>
                <a href="work.html" class="navbar-item" id="work-navbar-item" style="margin-right": 800px">Work</a>
                <a href="about.html" class="navbar-item" id="about-navbar-item" style="margin-right": 900px">About</a>
                <a href="assets/img/Li_Irene_Resume.pdf" class="navbar-item" id="resume-navbar-item" style="margin-right": 1000px>Resume</a>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
            <div id="intro">
            Hi! I'm Irene, <br>
            And I Am A <div class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Design Student" ]'>
                <span class="wrap"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you populating Design Student from something that pulls from the data-type?  Otherwise it stops after "And I Am A".  Also can you post the rest of the HTML?  Other elements can easily affect the layout of everything else on the page.

Comment: Hi! I have added the rest of my HTML. Also, I am using javascript to animate the typewriting.

Answer (score 0):

To position your text center-right, your best bet is to use flexbox on whatever is the parent container; see below.

Regarding changing the order of your menu links, you'd want to make a seperate SO post for that. You'd want to post your menu code and/or share what platform you're using.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#intro {
font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 34px;
line-height: 36px;
margin-top: 10%;
float: left;
animation-name: fade-in-from-top;
animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fade-in-from-top {
from { opacity: 0; margin-top: -30%; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="intro">
Hi! I'm Irene, <br>
And I Am A <div class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ 
"Design Student" ]'>
     <span class="wrap"></span>
</div>
</div>
```